# React useState hook - I want to render certain component when only press submit button not when onChange

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

I'm new to react.

Now trying to make form with react hooks, and I want to render Cloud component only when press submit button. But it rendered every onChange called.

I know that onChange re-rendered cause also useState hook.

But have no idea how to render only when press submit button.

My final goal is when write name and press enter, if value is not contained in api, setShake make shake True and if True, put shake-cloud class in Cloud.js.

REACT IS TOO DIFFICULT :(

Thanks for help tho :)

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faSearch } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import "./search.css";
import PageTitle from "./component/PageTitle";
import Cloud from "./component/Cloud";
import Loading from "./component/Loading";

//https://api.color.pizza/v1/
//data.colors[0].name

const App = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [colorNames, setColorNames] = useState("");
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
    const [cloudHex, setCloudHex] = useState("ivory");
    const [shake, setShake] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        getColorLists();
    }, []);

    const getColorLists = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`https://api.color.pizza/v1/`);
        const data = await res.json();
        await setColorNames(data);
        setIsLoading(true);
    };

    const isColor = () => {
        let makeUpper =
            query.search(/\s/) == -1
                ? query.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + query.slice(1)
                : query
                      .split(" ")
                      .map((i) => i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.slice(1))
                      .join(" ");

        for (let i = 0; i < colorNames.colors.length; i++) {
            if (colorNames.colors[i].name == makeUpper) {
                setCloudHex(colorNames.colors[i].hex);
                return;
            } else if (i == colorNames.colors.length - 1) {
                return makeShake();
            }
        }
    };

    const updateSearch = (e) => {
        setSearch(e.target.value);
    };
    const getSearch = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setQuery(search);
        isColor();
    };

    const makeShake = async () => {
        await setShake(true)
        await setShake(false)
    }

    return (
        <>
            {!isLoading ? (
                <Loading />
            ) : (
                <div className="App">
                    <div className="app-wrap">
                        <PageTitle />
                        <div className="search-wrap">
                            <form onSubmit={getSearch} className="search-form">
                                <input
                                    className="search-bar"
                                    type="text"
                                    value={search}
                                    onChange={updateSearch}
                                />
                                <button type="submit" className="search-button">
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                                        icon={faSearch}
                                        className="search"
                                    />
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <Cloud cloudhex={cloudHex} shake={shake} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Cloud.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCloud } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import './cloud.css';

const Cloud = ({cloudhex, shake}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        
    }, [])

    console.log(shake)
    return (
        <div className={`cloud-wrap ${ shake ? "shake-cloud":''}`}>
            <span className="cloudhexname">{cloudhex}</span>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCloud} className="cloud" style={{color:`${cloudhex}`}} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Cloud;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach in this case is to use `useRef()` Hook to store our search field value, instead of using `useState()`. Because `useRef()` `Hook does not force a re-render` while `useState()` does. This approach is known as `un-controlled` way to use input field.

You basically need to make few modifications in your code which are as follows:

```
const search = useRef("");
```

Then remove `onChange={updateSearch}` and `value={search}` from `input` and use a property `ref={search}`. So that your input looks like below:

```
<input 
    className="search-bar"
    type="text"
    ref={search}
/>
```

Then in the submit handler, you can get the value of the input field using `search.current.value`. So your `getSearch()` would look like

```
const getSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setClicked(true);
    setQuery(search.current.value);
    isColor();
};
```

Assuming user has typed an input. If not then you can set a validation before using setQuery() in the `getSearch()` form submit handler.

```
if(search.current.value){
   setQuery();
}
```

**Note:** **If you have any other `controlled inputs` in your project, you can change then to `un-controlled` inputs using `refs` and this way re-renders would not happen in your code.**

Comment: You are most most Welcome. I like to help people. God Almighty ALLAH gives me peace and tranquility. Yup Holidays are going good. Hope your's is good one too :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like that

If you want to render cloud component after form submit then put one flag and toggle that, here I take `clicked` state

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faSearch } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import "./search.css";
import PageTitle from "./component/PageTitle";
import Cloud from "./component/Cloud";
import Loading from "./component/Loading";

//https://api.color.pizza/v1/
//data.colors[0].name

const App = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [colorNames, setColorNames] = useState("");
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
    const [cloudHex, setCloudHex] = useState("ivory");
    const [shake, setShake] = useState(false);
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        getColorLists();
    }, []);

    const getColorLists = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`https://api.color.pizza/v1/`);
        const data = await res.json();
        await setColorNames(data);
        setIsLoading(true);
    };

    const isColor = () => {
        let makeUpper =
            query.search(/\s/) == -1
                ? query.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + query.slice(1)
                : query
                      .split(" ")
                      .map((i) => i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.slice(1))
                      .join(" ");

        for (let i = 0; i < colorNames.colors.length; i++) {
            if (colorNames.colors[i].name == makeUpper) {
                setCloudHex(colorNames.colors[i].hex);
                return;
            } else if (i == colorNames.colors.length - 1) {
                return makeShake();
            }
        }
    };

    const updateSearch = (e) => {
        setSearch(e.target.value);
    };
    const getSearch = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setClicked(true);
        setQuery(search);
        isColor();
    };

    const makeShake = async () => {
        await setShake(true)
        await setShake(false)
    }

    return (
        <>
            {!isLoading ? (
                <Loading />
            ) : (
                <div className="App">
                    <div className="app-wrap">
                        <PageTitle />
                        <div className="search-wrap">
                            <form onSubmit={getSearch} className="search-form">
                                <input
                                    className="search-bar"
                                    type="text"
                                    value={search}
                                    onChange={updateSearch}
                                />
                                <button type="submit" className="search-button">
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                                        icon={faSearch}
                                        className="search"
                                    />
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        {clicked && <Cloud cloudhex={cloudHex} shake={shake} />}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks!! And merry christmas ;)